# image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel - operator= missing

Tags: ros, image-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is it possible, that the operator=() is missing in the image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel? The following assertion is not true as expected.

```
void ClassA::setCameraModel( const image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel& cameraModel )
{
   mCameraModel = cameraModel; // fails, since no operator= implemented
   assert( mCameraModel.fx() == cameraModel.fx() );
}
```

a workaround would be to

```
void ClassA::setCameraModel( const image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel& cameraModel )
{
   mCameraModel.formCameraInfo( cameraModel.cameraInfo() );
   assert( mCameraModel.fx() == cameraModel.fx() );
}
```

Or is it not recommended to use the PinholeCameraModel that way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118911/image_geometry::pinholecameramodel---operator=-missing/) by [Tobias](https://answers.ros.org/users/825/tobias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I tried to contribute:

https://github.com/TobiasBaer/vision_opencv

---

Originally posted by [Tobias](https://answers.ros.org/users/825/tobias/) with karma: 156 on 2014-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) on 2014-01-17**:
You should submit a pull request to the upstream repository if your fix is good and works. If you need help doing that, follow the instructions at https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests